# How do I take this method I defined in the model and have it executed automatically once per day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is only the second rails app I've ever created so I new at doing this. If there is a better way of doing things then I'm open to hearing your suggestions but keep in mind that I'm learning right now.

I have a method in my model called twilio_api_call. It uses an api to send a text message to a specified phone number pulled out of the database. I would like this method to be executed once per day at 12pm without any user interaction. I am working off my localhost and plan to deploy this app to Heroku. How can I achieve this goal? Maybe pull out this code and place it in some external file that can be called automatically somehow?

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :selections
    has_many :movies, through: :selection

    has_secure_password

    def self.get_notifications
        Movie.find_by_sql("SELECT u.phone, m.title FROM users AS u INNER JOIN movies AS m ON u.id = m.user_id WHERE m.release_date::date = current_date")
    end

    def self.twilio_api_call
        # get user data to parse and send to Twilio api
        data = get_notifications
        # put your own credentials here 
        account_sid = 'insert sid here' 
        auth_token = 'token goes here'

        # data is array of hashes. Parse data.
        # loop through data hash, build Twilio code
        data.each { | key |
            phone_number = key["phone"]
            message = "Message from MovieTextAlert - the movie: '" + key["title"] + "' has been released today in theaters."

            # set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API 
            @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token 

            @client.account.messages.create({
                :from => '+18563176098', 
                :to => phone_number, 
                :body => message,
            })
        }

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem for such periodic actions

```
every 1.day, :at => '12:00 pm' do
  runner "User.twilio_api_call"
end
```

This code will execute your method everyday at 12:00 pm.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it could be so easy. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a certain web server that needs to work with the whenever gem?

Comment: @Ben No. You won't need anything. This gem will create & handle cron job to be executed.